# Difference between Apache Shiro and Central Authentication Service (CAS)

Tags: cas, shiro

[CAS](https://www.apereo.org/projects/cas)

[Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/)

I need to know the difference between CAS & Apache Shiro.
Are they both used for Single Sign On or does Apache Shiro depend on CAS for authentication

Comment: It sounds like you're wanting to know more about authentication vs authorization. Google for this and there is plenty on these often-confused concepts.

Comment: This question is relevant. This is not about authentication vs authorization but it is clear that the requester and myself too, are not clear about what does CAS provide vis-a-vis over and above Shiro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shiro is a security framework. CAS is a platform for enterprise Single SignOn. Shiro does not depend on CAS, and neither does CAS depend on Shiro. Shiro supports CAS so that you can use Shiro in your applications to authenticate via a CAS server, and CAS uses Shiro to allow you to authenticate to a variety of backend sources. They are both very different from each other.